# Why is doctrine updating every single object of my form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a big Symfony 2 form on a huge collection (over 10k objects). For simple reasons, I cannot display a form of thousands of objects. I am displaying a form of about 300 objects.

I have found no way to filter a collection into a form and thus do the following :

```
    $bigSetOfObjects = array(
        'myObject' => $this
                ->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('MyObject')
                ->findBy(... )
    );

    $form = $this->createForm(new MyObjectForm(), $bigSetOfObjects);

    // And a little further
    if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
        $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }
```

Everything works great. Form is displayed with the correct values and the update works fine also. Data is correctly saved to the database. The problem is that Doctrine is executing a **single update statement per object** meaning the whole page is about 300 SQL statements big causing **performance issues**.

What I do not understand is that I'm updating only a couple of values of the form, not all of them. So why is Doctrine not able to detect the updated objects and thus update only those objects in the database?

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I might have forgotten?

Comment: Can you add the code of your persists and flushes please?

Comment: I've added the flush code. Persist is done in fixtures.

Comment: Well, I think a request is bound to every object in the form. I would rather create a form for each object (not for all of them), check those that have been modified, and persist only those. In the worse case, you'll have to update them all (same as now), but the number of request will be function of the number of modified objects, and not of the number of objects in the form.
I hope it helps ^^

Answer (score 8):

By default Doctrine will detect changes to your managed objects on a property-by-property basis. If no properties have changed then it should not be executing an update query for it. You may want to check that the form isn't inadvertently changing anything.

You can, however, change how doctrine determines that an object has changed by modifying the [tracking policy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html). Since you are working with a lot of objects you may want to change to the `DEFERRED_EXPLICIT` tracking policy. With this method you would specifically call:

```
$em->persist($object);
```

on the entities that you want to be updated. You would have to implement your own logic for determining **if** an object needs to be persisted.